# strange rpm requirement: perl(a)

Tags: perl, rpm, nagios, ldd

I am packaging several parts of my company icinga installation as RPMs, to be used in the transaction from a central monitoring solution to a distributed one.

Along the way I have packaged the nagios plugins folder easily and I have discovered that newer versions of rpmbuild calculate requirements automatically using ldd.

Now my package has a huge list of unmet dependencies, mostly perl modules. Some of these requirements are cryptic or equivocal: I can't find anything about them in google or the repositories:

```
icinga.plugins-1.0-1.i686 has missing requires of perl(a)    
icinga.plugins-1.0-1.i686 has missing requires of perl(snmp)  #which module is this???
...
```

I guess I can find out most of them, but perl(a).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The comment is in the right place. I don't what is perl(a) and I don't know which snmp module is ldd referring to with perl(snmp)

Comment: That probably means that some perl script in the package has a line like `use a;` in it. You can probably find it if you look for it. It might be an internally provided perl module. The same for the `perl(snmp)` line. It is asking for anything that provides that perl module.

Comment: Those were both mismatches. In my scripts I have the following comments: "... to use snmp v2 ..." and "... they use a protocol ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable auto requirements at all, or manipulate the auto requirements mechanism to ignore specific requirements. Look here:

http://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2005-August/msg00461.html